# Installing Package in Laravel VIA Composer

Tags: laravel-4

i am currently using laravel 4 for my project, i download a package that turns youtube/vimeo urls into embed, i required the package in my composer and run composer update.

However now i am trying to use this package but i keep getting an error:

```
Class 'Embed' not found
```

The code for this is in my **helpers.php** file:

```
function embed_video($url, $width = 0, $height = 0)
{
    $embed = Embed::make($url)->parseUrl();

    if ($embed) {
        // Set width of the embed.
        if ($width > 0)
        {
            $embed->setAttribute(['width' => $width]);
        }

        // Set height of the embed.
        if ($height > 0)
        {
            $embed->setAttribute(['height' => $height]);
        }

        return $embed->getHtml();
    }

}
```

I call this function in my view.
This is the link for the package: [cohensive](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/cohensive/embed)

Comment: Have you added it to `providers` and `alias` in app/config/app.php ??

Comment: No i have not, laravel 4 did everything for me automatically. I'll do that.

Comment: For aditional details to what @ArkarAung stated, check the Installation process on the package's GitHub page: https://github.com/KaneCohen/embed